# Error Handling CRM 4 Webservice

Tags: python, web-services, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

What is the best way to trap errors/exceptions with the CRM 4 Web service.  Is there a way to get more detailed error messages from the web service?  There is a custom application that creates orders and when the get a error message from the web service it is not very details or useful.  Is there a better way to get more detailed message from the CRM 4 web service in a custom application written in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catch SoapException and take a look at Detail property. You'll find everything about the error in there.